# IBodyModelValidator custom implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Are there any examples/guides how to implement custom IBodyModelValidator for ASP.NET MVC WebAPI stack? Tried to google it but found nothing interesting...

Comment: Remove parameter name prefix from ModelState keys sample code.
http://takepara.tumblr.com/post/40139893495/configuring-asp-net-web-api-the-official-microsoft
Not changed validation rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of examples I agree.

It depends on what you are actually trying to achieve in your custom validation - but given the `DefaultBodyModelValidator` actually defers it's validation out to the correct validators for the model (by looking up the required validator via the `ModelValidatorProvidor`)... perhaps your logical extension point should instead be to implement a custom [`ModelValidatorProvidor`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463900/Creating-a-custom-ModelValidatorProvider-in-ASP-NE) ([example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463900/Creating-a-custom-ModelValidatorProvider-in-ASP-NE)) and then let the BodyModelValidator defer to it instead.

In any case the best example of how to implement a custom one is probably to look at the code for the Default one. This is available on the CodePlex site [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/effb15ece69a#src/System.Web.Http/Validation/DefaultBodyModelValidator.cs).

Comment: Yes, I already started to implement it the way you said. It seems, that ModelValidatorProvider is a good extension point. In my case I have my validation metadata in xml and validators based on EntLib. Btw, I'm really disappointed how Web API pipeline is implemented now: for every MVC component I should implement the same for Web API, and sometimes the approach is different (like in this case). Hope there will be one pipeline in next release.